# Issues with views.py in django to create comments

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to create a blog where I have posts and comments which are connected to spesific posts. Now I can list my posts and also have a detail view for them and my comments are also appearing under the posts. However it works only if I am creating the comments under the admin site. If I am commenting and click on submit nothing happens. Can you please help me.
Here are my files.

**views.py**

```
class PostList(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form=PostForm
    model = PostModel
    fields=['post']
    success_url="/home"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author=self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['postmodel_list'] = PostModel.objects.order_by('-created_on')
        return context




class PostDetail(LoginRequiredMixin,ModelFormMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = PostModel
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    form_class=CommentForm


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['commentmodel_list'] = CommentModel.objects.filter(post=self.object).order_by('-created_on')
        return context


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_valid(self, form):
           form.instance.post=self.object.post
           form.instance.author = self.request.user
           return super(PostDetail,self).form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.

class PostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='post_author')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.post)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.post}"


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('dictionary.PostModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_comment')
    comment=models.TextField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='comment_author')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("comment_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.comment}"
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import PostModel,CommentModel
from django import forms

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PostModel
        fields=['post','author']

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=CommentModel
        fields=['comment']
```

**EDIT**
I added the template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left mx-auto">
      <div class="card mb-4 block">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title">{% block title %} {{ postmodel.post }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
          <p class=" text-muted"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{%url 'user_profile' user.username %}">@{{ postmodel.author }} </a>| {{ postmodel.created_on }}</p>
          <p class="card-text ">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left mx-auto">
        {% for comments in commentmodel_list %}
        <div class="card mb-4 block">
            <a class="overlay" style="text-decoration:none" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> </a>
            <div class="card-body inner">
              <p style="text-align:right;float:right;margin-top:10px;" class="card-text text-muted h6"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{%url 'user_profile' user.username %}">@{{ comments.author }}</a> </p>
              <h2 class="card-title">{{ comments.comment }}</h2>
             
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-3 float-right ">
  <button style= "position: fixed; bottom:50px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add New Comment</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Comment</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT2**

I realised when I post a post with the user 1 and then try to add a comment to that post again with user1 nothing happens, when I login with user2 and then try to add a comment nothing happens again, but the post's author changes to user2.

Comment: In which url did your problem occur?

Comment: Just as a matter of fact, it will be really helpful to only include the parts that are really necessary to solve your problem

Comment: actually I got no problem as I mentioned after I create a comment and click on submit it redirects me to the succes url (postdetail) but no comment appears

Comment: I was no sure if the problem was on the views or on my models so I included all of them but thanks :)

Comment: "However it works only if I am creating the comments under the admin site. If I am commenting and click on submit nothing happens." This makes me think the issue is probably in your templates

Comment: Maybe yes but the comments are also not seen in the admin panel but I will edit the question and add the html file in just a second

Answer (score 0):

How about turning `self.object.post` into `self.get_object()` in `form_valid`?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the mistake is that I am saying form=self.get_form()

Comment: Try to add context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'post': self.object}) in get_context_data in DetailView.

Comment: do you mean instead of :         context ['commentmodel_list'] = CommentModel.objects.filter(post=self.object).order_by('-created_on')

Comment: I am trying this for 2 days but nothing changed

Comment: it doesn't changed anything :)

Comment: What 'dictionary.PostModel' does? Why not just PostModel?

Comment: where is it? I couldn' find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218617/discussion-between-bkrop-and-ekrem-ucuncu).